# I am not able to iterate over json after parsed

Tags: jquery, json, underscore.js

I am trying to loop an object, which receive from back-end. After I receive that, I am iterating once of the container, I am getting error message here instead of get a object values.

JSON link sample: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/TCSPage.json

Here is my function:

```
jsonConvertor = function (argument) {

    return {
        init : function (json) {
            var that = this;
            this.receivedJson = $.parseJSON(json); //i am parseing still not working
            console.log(this.receivedJson.DocPageDetails)
            // _.each(that.receivedJson.DocPageDetails, function (i, item) {
            //  console.log(i, item);
            // });
        }
    }
};

$.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10268257/TCSPage.json")

.error(function() {
    console.log('no page found error');
})
.done(function(json){
    var html = jsonConvertor().init(json);
})
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbyb1exm/1/)

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but I think that JSON notation doesn't allow comments. Check that and tell me if works. And also, checking you JSON structure, shoulnd't you use ``this.d.receivedJson.DocPageDetails`` (including that ``d``) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `//` comments inside JSON, so you have to sanitize it first. In this case it seems to be sufficient to remove all the `//-something-\n` sequences that follow (immediately or after some whitespace) a comma character. But even after that you should address `obj.d.DocPageDetails`, not `obj.DocPageDetails` - that's easy to check if you log the received object. So, here's one possible way to do what you wanted:

```
var uncommentedJSON = json.replace(/,\s*\/\/[^\n]*\n/g, ',\n');
var obj = $.parseJSON(uncommentedJSON);
$.each(obj.d.DocPageDetails, function (i, item) {
    console.log(i, item);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qk4rdLb2/). I've replaced `_.each` with `$.each`, as you didn't include `underscore` in your fiddle, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: can you show me a way to replace all empty elements to removed using the `regex` - please? - have a look in to resulted each of objects 'DocPageDetails' thanks in advace

Comment: That's task for `$.grep/filter`, not regex.